# Local and Remote DataSource to Kendo Treeview

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to populate the Kendo TreeView in which 2 nodes are local dataSource and the last node should be remote Datasource

Here is my code:

```
$("#AftermarketTreeView").kendoTreeView({
                            dataTextField: ["text", "text", "MC_ANALYSIS_NAME"],
                            dataSource: {
                                data: [
                                  {
                                      text: "Initiate",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Parts Selection", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Assumptions", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Team", haschildren: false },
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      text: "Analyze",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Part Attributes", haschildren: false },
                                        { text: "Aftermarket Evaluation", haschildren: false }
                                      ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                      text: "Monto Carlo",
                                      items: [
                                        { text: "Monto Carlo", haschildren: true }

                                      ]
                                  }
                                ],
                                schema: {
                                    model: {
                                        hasChildren: "items",

                                        children: {
                                            schema: {
                                                data: "items",
                                                model: {
                                                    hasChildren: "haschildren",
                                                    children: {
                                                        schema: {
                                                            // override the schema.data setting from the parent
                                                            data: function (response) {
                                                                return response;
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                        transport: {
                                                            read: {
                                                                url: ResolveUrl("/CreateMaintainAnalysis/GetMontoCarloData/"),
                                                                dataType: "jsonp",
                                                                data:onDataSendAnalysisID,
                                                            }
                                                        },
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

Using above code I am getting structure as below
Where Initiate and Analyze are Local DataSource and Monto Carlo is Remote DataSource but I don't want the node again to be Monto Carlo under it that should be the direct remote DataSource from Database

[image]
so help me in this to solve

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can change your read property to a function:

```
read: function(options) { /* here you can do the ajax call for the remote dataSource and then you can merge the local dataSource with the remote dataSource, you can create a new array to accomplish this. */ }
```

You can see a example in [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.read).
The idea is to use options.success(result); the result is the merged dataSource (remote and local).

Comment: I tried but as  I am new to Kendo..Not able to understand where and what needs to be placed